# How can I align my text in the terminal? (Java)

Tags: java, string, terminal, text-alignment

My code accepts 3 arguments, first (args[0]) is the text file, second (args[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tkI4.png)) is the number of characters per line and the final argument (args[2]) is not yet implemented but is the option of the alignment (Left, Center or Justify). 
Right now, I am trying to implement the left alignment and here is my code (the alignment code comes the last):

```
try {
    System.out.println("usage: java AlignText" + args[0] + " " + args[1] + " 
    " + args[2]);
    String[] text = FileUtil.readFile(args[0]);
    int paragraphs = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String string : text) {
        if (builder.length() > 0) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }
        builder.append(string);
    }

    String str = builder.toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = str.indexOf(" ",paragraphs);
    while (i>0){
        sb.append(str.substring(0, i).trim());
        sb.append("\n");
        str = str.substring(i);
        if(str.length()>paragraphs){
            i = str.indexOf(" ", paragraphs);
        }
        else {
            i = -1;
        }
    }
    sb.append(str.trim());
    sb.toString();
    //System.out.println(sb.length());
    String[] lines = new String[100];
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<sb.length();j++){
        if(sb.charAt(j) == '\n') {
            lines[index] = sb.substring(count,j).trim();
            System.out.printf("%20s"+"\n", lines[index]);
            //System.out.println("\n");
            count = j;
            index++;
        }
    }
```

And here is my output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you even format for Left alignment? You can just output the String, no?

Comment: @daniu Well I want it to be aligned in three optional ways

Comment: If you're going to use `printf` to do your alignment, you need to use the format `"%-20s"` to get left-alignment; you've got `"%20s"`, which gives right-alignment.   `printf` won't do center-alignment, so you'll be on your own for that option.

Comment: @KevinAnderson So how the center alignment works then? Is there a special option for that? Btw, the -20 does not do anything, it just displays '-' at the left of the terminal

Comment: Alignment basics: you have `String l` that you want aligned over width `w`. First do `l = l.trim()`. Now `l` is already left-aligned.  To right-align,  add `w - l.length()` spaces at the front of `l'; to center, add `(w - l.length())/2` spaces at the front of `l`.